Vim9script autoloading script results in undefined variable
I'm new to vim9script and taking reference from this section of the vim9 help file. However I keep on getting this error upon calling TermOpen: E121: Undefined variable: util
autoload/util.vim:
" vim: set sw=4 et:
vim9script

export def Open()
    call term_start(&shell)
enddef

plugin/termtoggle.vim:
" vim: set sw=4 et:
vim9script

if !has('vim9script')
    finish
endif

if exists("g:loaded_termtoggle") && g:loaded_termtoggle
    finish
else
    g:loaded_termtoggle = true
endif

g:termtoggle_terminals = []

import autoload '../autoload/util.vim'

command TermOpen util.Open()

I also tried copying the example found in the help file and that didn't work either with the same error. The plugin is loaded using packadd.
vim --version output:
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled Apr 01 2024 14:35:29)
Included patches: 1-252
Compiled by Arch Linux
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+arabic            +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +tcl/dyn
+autocmd           +float             +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+autochdir         +folding           +multi_lang        +terminal
-autoservername    -footer            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+balloon_eval      +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +gettext           +num64             +textobjects
+browse            -hangul_input      +packages          +textprop
++builtin_terms    +iconv             +path_extra        +timers
+byte_offset       +insert_expand     +perl/dyn          +title
+channel           +ipv6              +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+cindent           +job               +popupwin          +user_commands
+clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
+clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +vim9script
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +viminfo
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3/dyn       +virtualedit
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +visual
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +visualextra
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +vreplace
+cscope            +localmap          +ruby/dyn          +wildignore
+cursorbind        +lua/dyn           +scrollbind        +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +mksession         +smartindent       +writebackup
+diff              +modify_fname      -sodium            +X11
+digraphs          +mouse             +sound             +xattr
+dnd               +mouseshape        +spell             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +startuptime       +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         +statusline        -xpm
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +syntax            +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary        -xterm_save
-farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "/etc/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/sysprof-6 -pthread -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/cloudproviders -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/fribidi -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0 -march=x86-64 -mtune=generic -O2 -pipe -fno-plt -fexceptions -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection -g -ffile-prefix-map=/build/vim/src=/usr/src/debug/vim -flto=auto -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 
Linking: gcc -Wl,-E -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/perl5/5.38/core_perl/CORE -Wl,-O1 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,pack-relative-relocs -flto=auto -L/usr/local/lib -o vim -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lz -lharfbuzz -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lcairo-gobject -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE -lm -ltinfo -lelf -lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -L/usr/lib -ltclstub8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm 


Your sample works as-is, here, in 9.1.0 and 9.0.1544. Could you add the whole output of $ vim --version to the body of your question?

@romainl There.

I’m not sure the command syntax works that way even in vim9script, but I could be wrong.

I'm assuming its correct since the help file uses it that way

I was checking if g:loaded_termtoggle is true instead of false, dumb mistake. I also found that the plugin is getting sourced twice for some reason, so using get(g:, 'loaded_termtoggle', false) doesn't work if I don't use vim9script noclear
it should be
if exists("g:loaded_termtoggle") && !g:loaded_termtoggle
    finish
else
    g:loaded_termtoggle = true
endif


